# Composite Cat Cannot divide its immediate lower neighbors factorial without leaving a remainder

Tags: mathematics, knowledge, no-computers

Find this unique composite cat given the information in this title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is

> Four

Reason

> $\frac{3!}{4} = \frac{6}{4} = 1 + \frac{1}{2}$ leaves a remainder

Hint from question

> cat - may be **four** legs

Uniqueness

> 2 is the only even prime number. Before 4 , 2 occurs only once and 4 is a multiple of 2. And 3! = 6 = 3.2.1 has only one **2**, hence it leaves a remainder. 
> $$$$
> Whereas for other composite numbers say, $n$,  $(n-1)!$ has all the factors of $n$, and thus doesn't leave a remainder.

Comment: I mean, rot13(guerr yrnirf n erznvaqre jura qvivqvat gjb snpgbevny)....?

Comment: @El-Guest "Composite" cat.

Comment: @hexomino by now you should know I don’t know how to read